# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') in a .js file

Tags: react-native

I have this problem with a .js.
I have tried to change some ";" with "," and to see where the problem is by the lane but i can`t see the problem.

The code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Stylesheet } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
      <Text style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = (size) =>
  Stylesheet.create({
    radius: {
      borderRadius: size / 2,
      width: size,
      height: size,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 20 },
  });
```

and the problem is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at styles (src/components/RoundedButton.js.js:19:14

    at RoundedButton (src/components/RoundedButton.js.js:12:31
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `StyleSheet`. It is named `StyleSheet`**not** `Stylesheet`.